# What does na_rep parameter stands for?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking at [cat method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)  in Pandas

I can not grasp what is `na_rep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs about [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) says:

> When na_rep is None (default behavior), NaN value(s) in the Series are ignored.

```
Series(['a','b',np.nan,'c']).str.cat(sep=' ')  
'a b c'

Series(['a','b',np.nan,'c']).str.cat(sep=' ', na_rep='?')  
'a b ? c'
```